# Using FunctionContext.RetryContext throws Nullreference on ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I try to receive the number of retries in a ServiceBusTrigger: (from a servicebusqueue)

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

[Function("SyncQueue")]
public async Task HandleSyncEvent([ServiceBusTrigger("sync-events", Connection = "ServiceBus-ConnectionString")] string syncEvent, FunctionContext context)
{
   var retryCount = context.RetryContext?.RetryCount ?? 0;
   if (retryCount > 0) {}
}
```

But while the `RetryContext` is not null the underlying Properties (`RetryCount`, `MaxRetryCount`) throw a NullreferenceException when I try to access them.

Can I solve this *without* wrapping a try..catch around the property when there are no retries?

Stacktrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.GrpcRetryContext.get_RetryCount()
   at cse.Functions.HandleSyncQueue.<HandleSyncEvent>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\git\backend\services\src\Synchronization\cse.Functions\HandleSyncQueue.cs:line 26
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please post the full `StackTrace` of the exception.

Comment: @knittl no. I am aware about NullReferences :) As I wrote the Exception occurs in a property that is not in my control but from the Framework

Comment: @OleAlbers but you are already using null-safe navigation (`?.`) so there must not be an NRE.

Comment: This is exactly why I ask...

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Azure library you're using. Are you using `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc` version **1.4.1**?

Comment: Yes. But from Experience I expect more of a configuration issue than a bug

Comment: @OleAlbers I know that feeling, but when a `NullReferenceException` is thrown _inside_ third-party code, _it's not your fault_. I took a peek at some of the code in `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc` on GitHub and I saw a complete lack of ctor parameter validation, not even null checks, so I'm almost certain this is the fault of that library's authors.

Comment: @OleAlbers: What is the implementation of `RetryCount { get { …; } }`? It looks like the NPE is happening inside the getter, not in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `DeliveryCount` instead

Following the Docs this value should contain the exactly same value as `context.RetryContext.RetryCount-1`

so changing the Header to

```
[Function("SyncQueue")]
public async Task HandleSyncEvent([ServiceBusTrigger("sync-events", Connection = "ServiceBus-ConnectionString")] string syncEvent, int deliveryCount, FunctionContext context)
{
    if (deliveryCount > 1) {}
}
```

had the desired effect

Comment: The `DeliveryCount` is a property from the Service Bus message, not Functions SDK. I _suspect_ that SB trigger does not support retries (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages), and you're using the Isolated Worker SDK, that's why you get an exception. I suggest you follow up on the Functions SDK repo to see why `RetryContext.RetryCount` throws NRE as it was supposed to be addressed already according to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/316